# How to fix "cordova-plugin-googlemaps is not installed or ready yet" on IOS with Ionic 4

Tags: ios, google-maps, ionic-framework

I developed an application on Ionic 4 using GoogleMaps. I first developed on Android, then when I wanted to export my project to IOS problems appeared.

I would like to point out that I use the cordova-plugin-googlemaps "multiple_maps" version on Android, and that without it I hadn't managed to get the map to work on Android.

I installed the dependencies for my project :

- cordova prepare ios
- npm install @ionic-native/core@beta
- npm install @ionic-native/google-maps@beta
- ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-googlemaps --variable API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID="my android key" --variable API_KEY_FOR_IOS="my IOS key"

But with this last command, problems appeared. I could see in the console that android and browser were well installed, ios also thanks to "pod". 
So I'm trying to build on Xcode: I have errors that the file "GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h" is not found.

The solution I found is to open the Podfile file, and change the version of GoogleMaps from "2.7.0" by default, to the version "3.1.0". So I delete the Podfile.lock file and the Pods folder, and I restart a pod install.

Unfortunately, I still have the error "GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h is not found. ", but I managed once (unfortunately I don't know how anymore) to remove this error and launch this application.

Instead of the map, I have the error"[GoogleMaps] cordova-plugin-googlemaps is not installed or ready yet." . I'm pretty sure the code behind it is ok, since it works without any problems on Android.

Here are my differents informations :

OS : Mojave 10.14.5 (last version)
XCode : 10.2 (last version)
cordova : 8.1.2
cordova-ios : 5.0.1
ionic : 5.0.1

My cordova plugin list :

`cordova-clipboard 1.2.1 "Clipboard"
cordova-plugin-camera 4.0.3 "Camera"
cordova-plugin-device 2.0.2 "Device"
cordova-plugin-file 6.0.1 "File"
cordova-plugin-file-transfer 1.7.1 "File Transfer"
cordova-plugin-filepath 1.5.1 "cordova-plugin-filepath"
cordova-plugin-geolocation 4.0.1 "Geolocation"
cordova-plugin-googlemaps 2.6.2 "cordova-plugin-googlemaps"
cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3 "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard"
cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 3.1.2 "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview"
cordova-plugin-mauron85-background-geolocation 3.0.3 "CDVBackgroundGeolocation"
cordova-plugin-network-information 2.0.1 "Network Information"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 5.0.2 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.4.2 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.3 "Whitelist"
info.protonet.imageresizer 0.1.1 "Image Resizer"`

My package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^7.2.13",
    "@angular/core": "^7.2.13",
    "@angular/forms": "^7.2.13",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.13",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^7.2.13",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^7.2.13",
    "@angular/router": "^7.2.13",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.4.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.4.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^4.3.0",
    "@mauron85/cordova-plugin-background-geolocation": "3.0.3",
    "cordova-android": "8.0.0",
    "cordova-browser": "6.0.0",
    "cordova-clipboard": "1.2.1",
    "cordova-ios": "4.5.5",
    "cordova-plugin-camera": "4.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "6.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": "1.7.1",
    "cordova-plugin-filepath": "1.5.1",
    "cordova-plugin-geolocation": "4.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-googlemaps": "git+https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps.git#multiple_maps",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.0.5",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^3.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-mauron85-background-geolocation": "^3.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-network-information": "2.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "2.4.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "1.3.3",
    "cordova-windows": "4.4.2",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "info.protonet.imageresizer": "0.1.1",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard": "2.2.1",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.29"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "~0.12.3",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.13.8",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "~7.2.3",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "~7.2.3",
    "@angular/cli": "^7.3.8",
    "@angular/compiler": "^7.2.13",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^7.2.13",
    "@angular/language-service": "^7.2.13",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.3.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.8.1",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.17",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.8.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^5.8.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.8.1",
    "@ionic-native/background-geolocation": "^5.4.0",
    "@ionic-native/camera": "^5.5.1",
    "@ionic-native/clipboard": "^5.4.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/file": "^5.5.1",
    "@ionic-native/file-path": "^5.5.1",
    "@ionic-native/geolocation": "^5.4.0",
    "@ionic-native/google-maps": "^5.0.0-beta.27",
    "@ionic-native/image-resizer": "^5.5.1",
    "@ionic-native/keyboard": "^5.4.0",
    "@ionic-native/network": "^5.6.0",
    "@ionic-native/transfer": "^3.14.0",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "~1.4.0",
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "^3.2.3",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^11.0.1",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~10.14.2",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "cordova": "^8.1.2",
    "ionic4-rating": "^1.0.9",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~3.1.4",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.2",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.12.0",
    "typescript": "~3.1.6"
},
"description": "Test",
"cordova": {
    "platforms": [
        "windows",
        "browser"
    ],
    "plugins": {
        "cordova-plugin-geolocation": {
            "GEOLOCATION_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": ""
        },
        "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
        "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
        "cordova-plugin-device": {},
        "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
        "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {
            "ANDROID_SUPPORT_ANNOTATIONS_VERSION": "27.+"
        },
        "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
        "cordova-clipboard": {},
        "cordova-plugin-mauron85-background-geolocation": {
            "GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION": "11+",
            "ANDROID_SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION": "26+",
            "ICON": "@mipmap/icon",
            "SMALL_ICON": "@mipmap/icon",
            "ACCOUNT_NAME": "@string/app_name",
            "ACCOUNT_LABEL": "@string/app_name",
            "ACCOUNT_TYPE": "$PACKAGE_NAME.account",
            "CONTENT_AUTHORITY": "$PACKAGE_NAME"
        },
        "cordova-plugin-camera": {},
        "cordova-plugin-file": {},
        "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": {},
        "cordova-plugin-filepath": {},
        "info.protonet.imageresizer": {},
        "cordova-plugin-network-information": {},
        "cordova-plugin-googlemaps": {
            "API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID": "My_Key",
            "API_KEY_FOR_IOS": "My_Key",
            "LOCATION_WHEN_IN_USE_DESCRIPTION": "This app wants to get your location while this app runs only.",
            "LOCATION_ALWAYS_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": "This app wants to get your location always, even this app runs in background."
        }
    }
}
```

I would be grateful for every lead given, I'm really lost. Thank you for your help! If something is not clear, please ask i will try to explain it better.

Edit : I created a minimal project to reproduce the problem https://github.com/NuritArmelle/Bug-googlemaps-not-installed

Here are the steps i did to reproduce (on a Mac):

```
npm install
npm rebuild node-sass --unsafe-perm
ionic cordova platform add ios
ionic cordova prepare ios
npm install @ionic-native/core@beta
npm install @ionic-native/google-maps@beta
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-googlemaps#multiple_maps --variable API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID="my android key" --variable API_KEY_FOR_IOS="my IOS key"
```

At this point, when i tried to build, it already give me the error "GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h is not found." (and i was on xcworkspace this time).

Then i created my Podfile at the in platforms/ios (here are the content of it):

```
DO NOT MODIFY -- auto-generated by Apache Cordova
platform :ios, '8.0'
target 'Bug-Googlemaps-not-installed' do
    project 'Bug-Googlemaps-not-installed.xcodeproj'
    pod 'GoogleMaps', '~> 2.7.0'
end
```

Finally, I did a "pod install". Still the same problem, can't build cause of "GoogleMaps.h".

Answer (score 2):

I resolve in this way, follow changes I made:

1. Remove these folders: platforms, node_modules, plugins, www e package-lock.json.
2. Uninstall cordova: `sudo npm uninstall -g cordova`
3. Install cordova: `sudo npm install -g cordova`
4. Install SDK from google maps: `ionic cordova plugin add https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps-sdk.git`
5. Install plugin google maps: `ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-googlemaps --variable API_KEY_FOR_IOS="your_api_key"`
6. `ionic cordova platform add ios.`
7. `ionic cordova prepare ios.`
8. `ionic cordova debug ios.`
9. `open xcode.`